# Error in Capistrano deployment in localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano3

I am deploying my application on localhost using capistrano , but getting the below error:

**INFO [5f197b14] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/promo_app/ as chakreshwar@localhost
DEBUG [5f197b14] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/promo_app/
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for 127.0.0.1:22**

I am using the below gem for capistrano

```
gem 'capistrano'
gem 'capistrano-ext'
```

Below is the code of Deploy.rb

```
# config valid only for current version of Capistrano
lock '3.4.0'
 set :application, 'my_app'
set :repo_url, '/home/test/git_server/test_app.git'
```

set :deploy_to, '/home/test/projects/capistrano_deployment/my_app'

```
set :scm, :git

set :format, :pretty

# Default value for :pty is false
set :pty, true

set :default_stage, "staging"

namespace :deploy do

  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do

    end
  end

end
```

Below is my staging.rb:

```
    server 'localhost', user: 'username', roles: %w{app db web}#   


:other_value
    role :app, %w{localhost}#, my_property: :my_value
    role :web, %w{localhost}#, other_property: :other_value
    role :db,  %w{localhost}
```

Please tell if anything missed in it .

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that you cannot SSH to the destination box, in this case localhost. Try `ssh 127.0.0.1`, and make sure that works. The deployment should execute once that works.

In regards to your general config, a couple of notes:

- The `capistrano-ext` gem is obsolete, you can remove that.
- In `staging.rb`, you have duplicate directives. You should probably remove the lines beginning with `role` in favor of the line beginning with `server`.
- In `staging.rb`, make sure that `username:` is set to the SSH user with which you will log in.

Good luck!

Comment: Now , I am getting cap aborted!
SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known

Comment: server 'ssh 127.0.0.1', user: 'my_user_name', this is my staging.rb .I am a newbie to ubuntu & capistrano

Comment: Open a command line and run `ssh my_user_name@127.0.0.1`. Can you connect?

Comment: No , I cannot connect, Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 port:22, Connection refused

Comment: Use an openssh tutorial and get that set up first: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring Once that is working, you can try to set up Capistrano.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're missing an SSH server to connect on your on machine because you only have the client.

If you can't do `ssh 127.0.0.1`, use:

`sudo apt-get install openssh-server`

To install the ssh server